# How to create reference to buttons in JavaScript function to avoid repetition?

Tags: javascript

I have a function where I am managing two groups of buttons. Around half of the function is just repeating the same stuff for `prevButtonB` as I already did for `prevButtonA`.

How would I create this function in pure JavaScript without repeating myself twice?

```
function buttonListener( btn ) {
    var sameButton = false;

    if (btn.loc == "start") {
        if (prevButtonA) {
            prevButtonA.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
            if (prevButtonA == btn) {
                prevButtonA = null;
                sameButton = true;
            } else {
                prevButtonA = btn;
            }
        } else {
            prevButtonA = btn;
        }
    } else { // EVERYTHING BELOW IS JUST REPEATING THE SAME AS ABOVE.
        if (prevButtonB) {
            prevButtonB.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
            if (prevButtonB == btn) {
                prevButtonB = null;
                sameButton = true;
            } else {
                prevButtonB = btn;
            }
        } else {
            prevButtonB = btn;
        }
    } // END OF REPEATING CODE.

    console.log( "prevButtonA", prevButtonA );
    console.log( "prevButtonB", prevButtonB );

    if (sameButton == false) {
        btn.style.backgroundColor = "green";
        myFunction();
    }
}
```

My attempt, as requested, is below. This way, I am trying to create a reference to whichever `prevButtonA/B` I am trying to access, but this method will not set the previously pressed button's color back to blue.

```
function buttonListener( btn ) {
    var sameButton = false;
    var whichBtn;

    if (btn.loc == "start") {
        whichBtn = prevButtonA;
    } else {
        whichBtn = prevButtonB;
    }

    if (whichBtn) {
        whichBtn.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
        if (whichBtn == btn) {
            whichBtn = null;
            sameButton = true;
        } else {
            whichBtn = btn;
        }
    } else {
        whichBtn = btn;
    }

    console.log( "prevButtonA", prevButtonA );
    console.log( "prevButtonB", prevButtonB );

    if (sameButton == false) {
        btn.style.backgroundColor = "green";
        myFunction();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your attempt and any problems you encountered.

Comment: can you post complete Code ?

Comment: @Dexygen, I've added my attempt and commented on it. Simply put, my attempt does not affect ```prevButtonA/B``` at all. The console.log() just state: "undefined".

Comment: why not just toggle a class?

Comment: If I knew how to solve this, either by toggling a class or otherwise, I wouldn't ask for help. @epascarello if you have a solution, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested the code, but you can use logic something similar as below to prevent code duplication.

```
function buttonListener( btn ) {
  var sameButton = false;
  var prevButton;
  if (btn.loc == "start") {
    if (prevButtonA) {
      prevButton = prevButtonA;
    }
    if (prevButtonB) {
      prevButton = prevButtonB;
    }
  } else {
    prevButton = btn;
  }
  prevButton.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
  if (prevButton == btn) {
      prevButton = null;
      sameButton = true;
  } else {
      prevButton = btn;
  }
console.log( "prevButtonA", prevButtonA );
console.log( "prevButtonB", prevButtonB );
```